# How do I map Stream<List<double>> to List<double> in Dart Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

We are trying to cast a Stream<List> to List in Dart Flutter.

```
List<double> _DeadliftWeightsList(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
List <Weights?> weights = snapshot.docs.map((doc){
  Weights(
      date: doc.get('date') ?? DateTime.now(),
      weight: doc.get('deadLiftWeight') ?? 0);
}).toList();
final List<double> normalized = NormalizedData(weights);
return normalized;}



List<double> DLWeights() {
List <double> weights = [];
usersCollection.snapshots()
    .map(_DeadliftWeightsList).listen((List<double> weights1) {
  weights = weights1;
});
return weights;}
```

This is our Return List Function

```
 List<double> returnList (String key){
List<double> values = [];
if(key == "Dead Lift"){
  values = DLWeights();
}
else if (key == "Back Squat"){
  values = BSWeights();
}
else if (key == "Hip Thrust") {
  values = HTWeights();
}
else if (key == "Leg Press") {
  values = LPWeights();
}
else if (key == "Bench Press") {
  values = BPWeights();
}
else if (key == "Lateral Pulldown ") {
  values = LateralPDWeights();
}
else if (key == "Bicep Curl") {
  values = BCWeights();
}
else if (key == "Tricep Extension") {
  values = TEWeights();
}


return values;


}
```

These functions are meant to grab the data from the Stream and return a list. However it is not grabbing the data and is giving us a bad state error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short example of how you can convert a `Stream<List<double>>` to a `List<double>`:

```dart
Stream<List<double>> listOfDoubleStream() async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    yield [i.toDouble()];
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  List<double> result = await listOfDoubleStream().expand((e) => e).toList();
  print(result);
}
```

The `expand` method is equivalent to `flatMap` in some other languages. Calling expand allows you to convert `Stream<List<double>>` to a `Stream<double>`, and then calling `toList` will get you the `List<double>`.

Another approach would be to use collection-for and the spread operator `...` :

```dart
List<double> result = [
  await for (final item in listOfDoubleStream()) ...item,
];
```