# Getting bad state error trying to cast Stream<List<double>> to List<double> in Flutter using dart?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a bad state error when I try to cast a Stream<List> to List in Dart using flutter.

This is my function that takes the snapshots and maps them as Weights objects and normalizes the weights so that we can display them on a graph in our app.

```
List<double> _DeadliftWeightsList(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
List <Weights?> weights = snapshot.docs.map((doc){
  Weights(
      date: doc.get('date') ?? DateTime.now(),
      weight: doc.get('deadLiftWeight') ?? 0);
}).toList();
final List<double> normalized = NormalizedData(weights);
return normalized;

}
```

This is our Normalize Data function which normalizes the data in a list of weights objects and returns a list of double values of the normalized data:

```
List<double> NormalizedData (List<Weights?> weights) {
final List<int> array = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < weights.length; i++) {
  array.add(weights[i]!.weight);
}
final lower = array.reduce(min);
final upper = array.reduce(max);
final List<double> normalized = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
  normalized.add((array[i] - lower) / (upper - lower));
}
return normalized;

}
```

This is the function that we use to map the stream of double values from _DeadLiftWeightsList to a list of double values and return that list:

```
List<double> DLWeights() {
List <double> weights = [];
Stream<List<double>> stream = usersCollection.snapshots()
    .map(_DeadliftWeightsList);
stream.listen((weight1) {
  for (int x = 0; x < weight1.length; x++){
    weights.add(weight1[x]);
  }
});
return weights;

}
```

We're getting a bad state error when we try to cast the data and we don't understand why?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878927/how-do-i-map-streamlistdouble-to-listdouble-in-dart-flutter see my response, on that question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I map Stream<List<double>> to List<double> in Dart Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878927/how-do-i-map-streamlistdouble-to-listdouble-in-dart-flutter)